# Reflect AbstractValidator rules in ServiceStack's metadata page

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

Imagine you have the following simplified CustomerRequest class:

```
public class CustomerRequest : IReturn<CustomerResponse>
{
    public string OrgNumber { get; set; }
}
```

For this request, you have the following validator:

```
public CustomerValidator()
{
    RuleFor(r => r.OrgNumber).NotEmpty();
}
```

If you view ServiceStack's auto generated metadata page on http://[myService]/json/metadata?op=CustomerRequest, it will look like this:

```
NAME PARAMETER   DATA TYPE   REQUIRED
OrgNumber   body    string  No
```

As you can see, the parameter is marked as "Required: No" even though the validator requires it to exist and be not empty.

Is it possible to reflect the validator's rules in the metadata automatically? I know I can use `[ApiMember(IsRequired = false)]`, but I'd prefer to have it tied to the validator if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only declarative attributes show up on the metadata Pages as they can be statically inferred, any validators registered at runtime are opaque and cannot be statically inferred by ServiceStack.

Comment: Not sure why it needs to be statically inferred, wouldnt it be possible to simple read it in Runtime and update accordingly, when the metadata page is loaded?